# Toggle menubar Sublime Text 3

Tags: settings, sublimetext3

As the question says how do I format and bind in sublime-keymap - user.

This is my current user settings file.

```
[
    {"keys": ["alt+shift+f"], "command": "reindent", "args": {"single_line": false}},
    { "keys": ["ctrl+k"], "command": "toggle_toolbar" }
]
```

My question is as following. what is the `"command"`

That lets me toggle the following bar:
[image]

On and and off. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
{ "command": "toggle_menu" }
```

Was the correct command I was looking for.